# Get JSON data from Parse.com database using HTTP request

Tags: json, rest, parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com and have some data stored in my database class (musical_data).

Is it possible to send a get request in my browser and have it return JSON to me? I have tried to retrieve the data, but can't figure out how to display the database class data in JSON via my browser.

Thanks

Example, this CURL form works.. But I want to type it into the browser url bar.

```
  curl -X GET \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: wfwefwefwef" \
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: wefwefwe123" \
    https://api.parse.com/1/classes/musical_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This format should work in the browser:

```
https://APPID:javascript-key=JSKEY@api.parse.com/1/classes/musical_data
```

Replace APPID with your application id and replace JSKEY with your JavaScript key